# SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc (.) in 3rd party css

Tags: css, angular, build, gulp

I try to run

```
✗ gulp build:dist
```

and i get this error:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc (.)
File: /Users/eladb/.../public/js/min/vendor.js
Line: 110474
```

It has no stack in my code, so i have opened vendor.js at line 110474

all i saw is an error in css of 3rd party component.

```
})(window, window.angular);

.lf-ng-md-file-input {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.lf-ng-md-file-input .lf-ng-md-file-input-preview-container {
```

how can i fix it if it's not my css code?

[image]

Comment: I see that everything up to line 11069 is JavaScript, and then it suddenly changes to css, without warning. That can't be right. Did you (or someone) paste the css into this js file by mistake?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand, as it's an auto generated file. even if i re-generate it - the output remains.